# Could Agora support another storage vendor different from the vendors that Agora provided?

Tags: agora.io

I'm currently using Agora for recording the audio calls. But Agora only supports vendors in the following list:
0: Qiniu Cloud
1: Amazon S3
2: Alibaba Cloud
3: Tencent Cloud
4: Kingsoft Cloud
5: Microsoft Azure
6: Google Cloud
7: Huawei Cloud
8: Baidu AI Cloud
Could I use another S3 vendor for storage audios? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Agora only supports the vendors on this list.